# Algorithm of matching with Solr (or elasticsearch)

Tags: algorithm, search, solr, elasticsearch, matching

I have to create an algorithm which returns a matchin percentage of result.

The purpose of this algorithm is to look for in a database according to several fields and to rerelease a percentage from matching between the query and the document.

At present I use Solr for my search but he don't return a percentage of matching but a score which cannot be converts in percentage.

I looked at Elasicsearch who is based on lucene too and I have no impression that I can take out with there.

Would you have solutions for me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lucene/Solr there isn't max score so that you can normalize your score. You can use the score of first result of the query as a maxScore but it is not correct way because it will depend on the current query. You can't make any differentiation over the other queries.

It is also not recommended on the Solr Wiki. Read [ScoresAsPercentages](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages) document.

Comment: Thanks,  this is why I'm looking for a technologie which made this... A lucene client or Other... Any ideas ?